# Java doc overlap the error message in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, compiler-errors, syntax-error, javadoc

I am using IntelliJ IDEA (2016.3) `linux version` for `Java` development. As shown in the image below when the mouse pointer hover over an error line, the error message is overlapped by the `javadoc` making it harder to read the given error message. How to fix this?. Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100949 could be related.

Comment: Another related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158262.

Comment: Also see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176328

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I use 2017.1.3 EAP on Win10 and it is the same. Seems like a bug.
There are several workarounds:

1. Set time delay for documentation popup to a higher value. This should give you more time to read the error message. *(Settings -> Editor -> General -> Show quick documentation on mouse move)*.
2. Set a cursor at the code with the error and you will see a duplicated error message in the status bar.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 1):

You can also have the documentation in a fixed spot by clicking the pin in the top right corner of the pop-up. The window will then always be there, but it does update on mouse-overs and it is not over the warning- and errormessages anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me in Android Studio and I've just removed documentation on mouse hover setting and set a Shortcut Key (Alt+D) for that. This is more comfortable for me.